# Measure Ping In WEBRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am working on a WEBRTC platform meeting. I need to measure the ping of the user with response of WEBRTC. If there is a library or you can make me a JavaScript function...

Comment: Hey, have you had a look at this https://github.com/groupboard/pingtest ? It will require some work on your side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a cloud-hosted performance test with a webRTC data round trip time assertion. It can help with your measures.
Here is a blog post about creating an automated test for a webRTC app: https://blog.loadero.com/2020/08/10/how-to-set-up-an-automated-webrtc-test-with-loadero/

Adding a post-run assertions: https://blog.loadero.com/2020/01/29/how-to-get-the-best-out-of-post-run-assertions/

There you can add an assertion for data round trip time (rtt), some additional info on this:https://wiki.loadero.com/test-creation/asserts-1/asserts#webrtc-statistics-asserts

You can set and run those tests for free in a trial.